# Reuse data from Object in test

Tags: java, mockito

I have some test

```
 private DataJpa myObject = new DataJpa();
 private DaoService daoService = mock(DaoService.class);
 private RestServiceImpl service = spy(RestServiceImpl.class);

 @Before // I've tried @BeforeClass too
 public void init(){

   service.setDaoService(daoService);
   when(daoService.selectObject(anyString())).thenReturn(myObject);
}

@Test
public void test1(){

   Response registerFirstResponse = service.registerDevice(serialNumber, token, registrationDeviceRequest);

   createMyObjectJpa(field1,field2,field3);

   Response registerSecondResponse = service.registerDevice(serialNumber, token, registrationDeviceRequest);

   assertEquals(Response.Status.CREATED.getStatusCode(), registerFirstResponse.getStatus());
   assertEquals(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), registerSecondResponse.getStatus());
}

 private void createJpa(field1,field2,field3){
        myObject.setDeviceId(field1);
        myObject.setPushToken(field2); 
}
```

And my `registerDevice` method inside `service`

```
 public Response registerDevice(String serialNumber, String token, String registrationDeviceRequest){
    DataJpa jpa=daoService.selectObject(serialNumber);
        if(jpa==null){
           //here I must fulfill my jpa 
            dataJpa = StaticUtils.createJpa(field1,field2,field3);
            return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).build();
        }else{
             return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
        }
}
```

So, after first call `doMyMethod` my `myObject` fulfils some data like `testField`, but on the second call I expect that `myObject` has already that data, but I get `null` in `myObject`  and it fulfils again.

I need to test, that it returns Response about `myObject` if it has some data inside it.

How to save different fields into `myObject` till the second call?

**EDIT**

How to you can test my problem. When you try to call `responseSecondClass1` so inside `Class2.testClass()` on the `if` statement you will get null, but I need that it will be fulfiled object;

```
public class Class1 {

    String field1;
    String field2;
    String field3;

    public Class1() {
    }

    public Class1(String field1, String field2, String field3) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
    }

}

public class Class2 {

    public Response testClass() {

        Class1 class1 = getMyObjectFromMethod();

        if (class1 == null) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_MODIFIED).build();
        }
    }


    public Class1 getMyObjectFromMethod() {

        Class1 class1 = new Class1("field1", "field2", "field3");
        return class1;
    }
}

@Test
    public void test1() {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        Class2 class2 = spy(Class2.class);
        when(class2.getMyObjectFromMethod()).thenReturn(class1);

        Response responseFirstClass1 = class2.testClass();

        class1 = fulfilClass();
        Response responseSecondClass1 = class2.testClass();

        assertEquals(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), responseFirstClass1.getStatus());
        assertEquals(Response.Status.NOT_MODIFIED.getStatusCode(), responseSecondClass1.getStatus());

    }

    private Class1 fulfilClass() {
    Class1 class1 = new Class1("field1", "field2", "field3");
    return class1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to use doAnswer instead

```
when(daoService.selectObject(anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer<DataJpa>() { 
    @Override 
    public DataJpa answer(InvocationOnMock iom) throws Throwable { 
        return myObject; 
    } 
});
```

Or it is possible to use something like

```
when(daoService.selectObject(anyString())).thenReturn(myObject);
Response registerFirstResponse = service.registerDevice(serialNumber, token, registrationDeviceRequest);

   createMyObjectJpa(field1,field2,field3);
   when(daoService.selectObject(anyString())).thenReturn(myObject); // here `myObject` was changed and now I say to Mockito, I want my new `myObject`

   Response registerSecondResponse = service.registerDevice(serialNumber, token, registrationDeviceRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling `doMyMethod` twice in the same test, I think you should explicitly tell Mockito what to return in the second call.

Something like that:

```
when(myClass.doMyMethod(any()))
  .thenReturn(myObject)
  .thenReturn(myObject);
```

And if you need different responses, you can do something like that:

```
 when(myClass.doMyMethod(any()))
  .thenReturn(myObject1)
  .thenReturn(myObject2);
```

Or even maybe

```
when(myClass.doMyMethod(any()))
  .thenReturn(myObject)
  .thenThrow(new MyException(...));
```

Comment: Hmm, it is a good variant, but I should got 2 difference `answer` in each call

Comment: I've changed my question inside method

Comment: @Dred I updated my answer :-) Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: It looks, that I must create 2 different objects like `MyObject myObject1=new MyObject(); myObject1.setField("something"); MyObject myObject2=new MyObject(); myObject2.setField(myObject1.getField());` it looks so hard...